# CORS error when updating a contact in Stamplay

Tags: angularjs, cors, stamplay

When calling
JavaScript

```
Stamplay.Object('contact').update()
```

I'm getting this error:

JavaScript
PUT https://myappid.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/contact
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myappid.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/contact.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: You have to enable the cors on server side..

Answer (score 0):

You need CORS support in the response of https://myappid.stamplayapp.com/api/cobject/v1/contact which means the HEADER should contain something like the following line:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com
```